# How to insert sub questions when setting a quizzes in moodle

Tags: moodle

When setting quizzes in moodle i want to add sub questions with the main question. I tried more and more with the existing question types and plugins and could not find a way. Is there an easy way or proper way? Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the qtype_combined plugin, developed by the OU:

https://moodle.org/plugins/view/qtype_combined

From the plugin page:

> This question types uses other question types as sub questions. It allows you to have one or more entry fields for any of these question types embedded in your question text. You must have at least one of these question types installed for this combined question type to work :
>
> 1. Variable numeric (the variable numeric question type in turn requires variable numeric set)
> 2. Pattern match
> 3. OU multiple response and / or
> 4. Select missing word

All of these are available from the plugins page as well.